# Run capybara in rake task

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, capybara

How can I run Capybara functionality in Rake task?

for example: `visit('http://google.com')`

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Try something like this in the task:

```
require 'capybara'
require 'capybara/dsl'

Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
Browser = Class.new { include Capybara::DSL }
page = Browser.new.page
page.visit("http://www.google.com")
puts(page.html)
```

Comment: Thank you! That works really fine! Could you tell me, how to set increase default timeout?

Comment: well, capybara configuration is a different matter, though I've never needed to tweak with the timeout. Check the docs: http://rdoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara#timeout-class_method.