# Ruby get HTML source w/ dynamic content

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to load the dynamic content of a page as well as the static HTML. For example, at http://www.balsamiq.com/ if I just load the HTML it will be missing the large testimonials box at the bottom of the page. I know I can load the html using

```
html = open(url).read
```

But again, this will be missing the dynamic content that shows when the page loads. How can I get the complete HTML that matches what a human gets when viewing the site? Thanks!

Comment: You need to run javascript also. I heard that Selenium can help here.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but it seems like Selenium is better for performing automated tasks and testing. I just need the page load to be performed. I'm looking for information on webpages that is very often dynamically loaded instead of in the html source. When you view source on browsers you still don't get the information I'm looking for.

Comment: I've used capybara for things like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7457245/run-capybara-in-rake-task

Comment: Capybara would work if I didn't need the javascript execution. All the drivers that allow js require some other framework (qt for webkit, phantomjs for poltergeist, firefox for selenium) and I'm going to be deploying this to a heroku server where I can't really install those libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved my problem by using the [Mechanize](https://github.com/tenderlove/mechanize) ruby gem and setting the user_agent. Though not necessarily an answer to my question, I set user_agent to a search bot and the pages with javascript displayed themselves in a less dynamic form.

Answer (score 0):

watir might also be helpful to you here.